# Laravel log files could not be opend, permission denied

Tags: laravel, file-permissions, ubuntu-server

I am running a laravel application on a ubuntu server. There a number of cron job running for on a hourly basis. 
The problem is, sometimes the application throws an error that the log file could not be opened because the permission is denied. If i update the directory permission it solves the issue. But it is not possible to check and fix the issue continuously.

What might the reason of changing the directory permission automatically and how can i solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Give recuresive permision

```
sudo chmod 775 -R storage/logs
```

Comment: You should NEVER give a 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

if youre ubuntu user
just run this

```
sudo chown -R USER:www-data storage
```

much proper for nginx. change the storage group ownership and bootstrap/cache directory to www-data

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using Ubuntu in which case you the current user may not have the permission to write to it.
Use this command to regrant yourself read-write privileges for the entire storage folder.

**`sudo chown -R $USER storage`**